# knockoutjs 'Cart editor' example having jquery validation plug-in issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, knockout.js

I took the original 'Cart editor' example at http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html (jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/) and added jquery validation plugin into it. I want to validate against the 1st `Category` select list to make it required. So I made the the following changes:

- made submit button just a straight `type=submit` input
- surrounded the controls in a `<form>`
- execute `$("form").validate()` at the end of script
- added `class='required'` in the `<select>`
- added `uniqueName: true` in `data-bind`

Here's the jsFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/niner/JXJtj/3/. So the validation will work if the `category` list has nothing in it. However, if I make a valid selection (i.e. Motorcycles), when I press 'submit', it still says 'The field is required.'. Even if I selected all the other choices correctly, I still get validation error on the `category` select control. Can someone please take a look and let me know what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/72puP/.  Will add more detail on the forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your options have a value, so validation always fails because `.val()` always returns an empty string.  You can give your options a value by adding `optionsValue: "name"` to your `data-bind` expression:

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/JXJtj/4/

Comment: Thanks. I see why the `value` is needed. In the example now, the 1st select list would not cascade down to populate the 2nd select list. Any idea why adding `optionsValue: "name"` breaks the cascade?